# Cannot float the contents of the grid-view correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got a grid product in the class grid-product that contains products. But as shows the picture the 4th product is badly places.

here is the style of the product grid

```
.grid-product {
    display: block;
    margin: 2% 0;
}
```

[image: GRID OF PRODUCT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving a fixed `height` for the `.grid-product` will fix it, because of irregular height, this happens.

```
.grid-product {
    display: block;
    margin: 2% 0;
    height: 300px;
}
```